# How do I enable a dropdown menu after hovering?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**How do I enable a dropdown menu after hovering over the border-radius circle or the text, and move the direction of the dropdown menu so it will be displayed above-right instead of hovering just the button and dropping down horizontally? I would like the button to be covered over the text but stays the same size**

```css
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
* {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}
:root {
    --pri-color: #F8A909;
    --background-color: #FFFAF0;
}

/* Start login */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.dropdown_com {
 position: relative;
 top:75px;
 left:180px;
 transform: translate(0px,0px);
}

.dropdown_com .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;  
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: 'Lato';font-size: 23px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: -165px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

.dropdown_com:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.compliments1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;   
    transform: translate(0px);
    border: 2px solid rgb(211,211,211);
    width: 210px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background:rgb(211,211,211);
}
.border-circle1{
    min-width: 1349px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70%;
    display: flex;
}
.border-circle1 li{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
 
}  
.fa-10x1{
    opacity: 0.3;
    font-size:7em !important;
    transform: translate(50px, 30px);
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit; 
}
.compliments1 p{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(20px,80px);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Lato';font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <jsp:include page="../head.html" />

    <body style="height: 100rem;">

        <!-- navigation bar -->


        <div class="border-circle1">
         
            <div class="compliments1">
                <a href="#"> <li><span class= " fa fa-thumbs-up fa-10x1"></span></li></a>
                <p> Facebook Like </p> 
                <div class="dropdown_com">
                    <button class="dropbtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">1 Likes</a>
                        <a href="#">2 Likes</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>

         

        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your description of what you want is very confusing, can you please explain clearly what the output you want?

Comment: Hi sorry about this. So, basically after hovering over the text with the mouse cursor, it would drop down a menu, instead of just hovering the button itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lots of things in your code which should not be there, I don't know why you have it there, For example there is a `span` with class `fa fa-thumbs-up fa-10x1` in `li`, and that `LI` is in a anchor, and ideally it should be in UL, LI should always be the child of UL or OL, not of anchor. For your drop-down problem, just make the display block of your List on hover of circle.

```css
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
* {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}
:root {
    --pri-color: #F8A909;
    --background-color: #FFFAF0;
}

/* Start login */
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.dropdown_com {
 position: relative;
 top:75px;
 left:180px;
 transform: translate(0px,0px);
}

.dropdown_com .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;  
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: 'Lato';font-size: 23px;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: -165px;
        background: #fff;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

.dropdown_com:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.compliments1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;   
    transform: translate(0px);
    border: 2px solid rgb(211,211,211);
    width: 210px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background:rgb(211,211,211);
}
.border-circle1{
    min-width: 1349px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 70%;
    display: flex;
}
.border-circle1 li{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
 
}  
.fa-10x1{
    opacity: 0.3;
    font-size:7em !important;
    transform: translate(50px, 30px);
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit; 
}
.compliments1 p{
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(20px,80px);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Lato';font-size: 28px;
}
.compliments1:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <jsp:include page="../head.html" />

    <body style="height: 100rem;">

        <!-- navigation bar -->


        <div class="border-circle1">
         
            <div class="compliments1">
                <a href="#"> <li><span class= " fa fa-thumbs-up fa-10x1"></span></li></a>
                <p> Facebook Like </p> 
                <div class="dropdown_com">
                    <button class="dropbtn">
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">1 Likes</a>
                        <a href="#">2 Likes</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>

         

        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```